# Use log4j 2 for writing to data files or database table

Tags: log4j2

I used log4j (v. 1) in the past and was glad to know that a major refactoring was done to the project, resulting in log4j 2, which solves the issues that plagued version 1.

I was wondering if I could use log4j 2 to write to data files, not only log files.

The application I will be soon developing will need to be able to receive many events from different sources and write them very fast either to a data file or to a database (I haven't decided which yet).

The thread that receives the events must not be blocked by I/O while attempting to write events, so log4j2's Asynchronous Loggers, based on the LMAX Disruptor library, will definitely fit this scenario.

Moreover, my application must be able to recover either from a 'not enough space on disk' or 'unable to reach database' conditions, when writing to a data file or to a database table, respectively. In other words, when the application runs out of disk space or the database is temporarily unavailable, my application needs to store events in memory and wait for storage to become available and when it does, write all waiting events to disk or database.

Do you think I can do this with log4j?

Many thanks for your help.

Regards,
Nuno Guerreiro

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

I'm aware of at least one production implementation in a similar scenario, where in gathered events are written to disk at high throughput.

Write to a volume other than your system volume to minimize the chances of system crashes due to disk space overrun.

Upfront capacity planning can help in ensuring h/w configuration with adequate resources to handle projected average load and bursts, for a reasonable period of time.

Do not let the system run out of disk space :). Keep track of disk usage, and proactively drop older data in extreme circumstances.